# Number of requests in cxf service

Tags: cxf, mule

I use mule CE 3.3.0. My project has the following:

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.3/mule-spring-security.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd ">

<global-property name="allowed" value="192.168.3.76,192.168.3.74,192.168.3.75" />

<configuration>
    <expression-language>
        <global-functions>
            def parseIp(fullIp) {
            return fullIp.substring(fullIp.indexOf('/') + 1, fullIp.indexOf(':'))
            }
    </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>

<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager
        xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="weather" password="weather" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<flow name="OML_News" doc:name="OML_News">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="9091"
        path="iran/oml_news" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
    <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <expression-filter
        expression="#['${allowed}'.contains(parseIp(message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']))]"
        doc:name="Expression" />        

    <cxf:proxy-service 
        service="Weather"
        wsdlLocation="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl"
        namespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
        validationEnabled="true" doc:name="SOAP">
    </cxf:proxy-service>

    <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" doc:name="Property" />

    <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="SOAP" />

    <outbound-endpoint 
        address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic">
    </outbound-endpoint>

</flow>
```

I launch a cxf service. There are some customers who use wsdl address in my cxf service and they implemented web services. Now I want that will be possible to determine how many users are using my wsdl address and each of them how many requests do send to my server? In fact, I want create a report system.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this, for example you can add a wiretap after your http inbound endpoint and invoke either a custom component that gather statistics in a database or more elegantly call a flow that does this.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://yourendpointaddress:8080/path" />
<wire-tap>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="stats" />
</wire-tap>
```

And then

```
<flow name="statsFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="stats" />
    <!-- gather stats from the headers -->
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insertStatsIntoDB" />
</flow>
```

This should gather statistics without affecting performance.

Comment: Thanks @Juan, when I use my wsdl address directly, this solution work correctly but when I create a portlet with "wsdl" as a web service and deploy it in my portal, this solution doesn't work and my statistics is wrong. because I want to have an exact statistics of requests to my portlet that uses my WSDL that I configured it in MULE